# What is error in this C program?

Tags: c, gcc

I have made two simple program, but getting unexpected answer. Can someone help?

```
//main program
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
float main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
float a,b,c;
a=5; b=10;
c=sum(a,b);
printf("%f + %f = %f \n",a,b,c); 
return (0);
}

//sum program
#include<stdio.h>
float sum (float a,float b)
{
float c;
c=a+b;
return(c);
}
```

The output of this program gets erroneous. I don't understand why. I compiled program with gcc. Can someone comment?

Comment: what means "The output of this program gets erroneous"?

Comment: Answer is wrong with this simple addition.

Comment: And how `main` know what is sum?

Comment: Is it technically wrong to use float main? I mean it should return 0.0  or something them. Am I correct?

Comment: I also never have seen `main` declared as `float`... but I think that it is not a problem... I'm going to check :D

Comment: And how main know what is sum?: there is function sum() created. Is this you are looking?

Comment: It seems that you have declared `sum` in other file...

Comment: Ok, definitely you should not declare `main` as `float`

Comment: This about main: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: And those `return(x)`... why the `()`?

Comment: Never seen `float main()` before in my life until this week, seen it 3 times on here.... what's going on

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are some tips...

1. Never put the arguments in the main function.
2. It's better to have a main block with no return value(void)
3. The header files should be used only once..
4. It's better to have other functions before the main block. Or else write the prototype of the function.

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
float sum(float a,float b)
{
 float c;
 c=a+b;
 return(c);
}
void main()
{
 float a,b,c;
 a=5; b=10;
 c=sum(a,b);
 printf("%f + %f = %f \n",a,b,c);
}
```

Hope this helped u :)

Comment: Except 3 the other three tips you gave are a little weird. Why not to do 1,2 or 4?

Comment: In standard C, `main` should always be either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` ...anything not equivalent to these is not portable.

Answer (score 4):

This should be your actual code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

float sum (float,float);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float a,b,c;
    a=5; b=10;
    c=sum(a,b);
    printf("%f + %f = %f \n",a,b,c); 
    return (0);
}

//sum program
float sum (float a,float b)
{
    float c;
    c=a+b;
    return(c);
}
```

Initially you did not mention the prototype for `sum` and normally as per C99 it ought to default to `int` so your code will not compile - and also you included `stdio.h` twice and you included `conio.h` without reason. Also `main` as per ISO should return an `int` and not `float` and `conio.h` is non-standard.

Comment: See? Now I can believe that `main` knows about `sum`

Comment: The most important thing here is that `sum` must be declared before it is used. Otherwise the compiler will assume it is accepting and returning `int`s and interpret the results incorrectly.

Comment: The code would compile in C89, it defaults to `int sum();`. However it is undefined behaviour. Since there is no prototype, the arguments undergo the default argument promotions, so `float` promotes to `double`. But the function expects `float`.   The wrong type being returned is another instance of UB.

Answer (score 1):

Function declaration is always before the main function and you can also write the function definition before the main function. That's your error!

Try this instead :

```
//main program
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

float sum (float a,float b)
{
   float c;
   c=a+b;
  return(c);
}

float main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
      float a,b,c;

      a=5; b=10;

      c=sum(a,b);
      printf("%f + %f = %f \n",a,b,c);
      getch();
     return (0);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My compiler complains only about `float main(int argc, char* argv[])`, says it wants `int`, but the rest seems ok.